# waitForText('locator', 'mytext') function doesn't assert exact text, it passes the test even substring is matched

Tags: karate

I am asserting below:

```
waitForText('locator', 'Preferences')
```

It is passing test in below scenarios(which is not correct):

1. waitForText('locator', 'Preference') -- removed 's' from 'preferences'

Doest this function match substring? Same behaviour i observed with
match text('locator') == 'expected string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is explained in the docs. Since 90% of teams need this, that is the default: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waitfortext

If you really want an exact match, that's easy:

```
* match text('locator') == 'some text'
```

Or if you want the "wait" (refer [tree walking](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#tree-walking)):

```
* def el = waitFor('locator')
* match el.text == 'some text'
```

You can always write your own super-custom "wait" using [`waitUntil()`](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#waituntilfunction).